# PHONE GAP android APPLICATION using CLING

Tags: android, cordova, android-cling

I want to make a PHONE GAP android application using the cling library, which is used to detect all the upnp devices which are available in the same wifi network .

The links which I have followed so far are as follows.

1. phonegap:- http://phonegap.com/
2. cling library:- http://4thline.org/projects/mailinglists.html#nabble-td4025045

I already made an android app using cling to detect the devices but now I want to make this app using PHONEGAP(for multiple platforms like IOS,WINDOWS,ANDROID)

Any documentation will be accepeted

I am done with basic hello world application using phonegap android

Answer (score 0):

You can search if there is already a plugin for that or you will have to build your own plugin following the docs : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Be carefull not to follow old tutorials about plugin creation, be sure it's at least about cordova 3 and talking about the plugin.xml file.

Comment: ya i have tried to search it but in vain , it will be a great help if you could help me in making a new plugin ! cheers , anyways thanks for replying !

Comment: The thing I did when I had to do my first plugin is I downloaded some simple cordova plugins, played with the files (changed the namespaces, the file names... and voila) that's not so hard. Have a look at dialogs plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs) or vibration plugin. (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration)